# San storage HP p4300 g2 iscsi volume

Tags: storage-area-network, network-storage, storage

I have a p4300 SAN storage in my network, I create a volume and assign that to TWO servers, i cant sync data between two volume and any change in one of them dont appear to another, how i can do that?

Answer (score 4):

I imagine you're not using a cluster-aware file system, you're probably using something like FAT, NTFS, ext2/3/4, XFS etc. You'll need to use a cluster file system such as OCFS2, Microsoft Cluster-Services enhanced NTFS, Veritas Storage Foundation, VMFS or others. This is a very basic but all too commonly misunderstood problem for junior storage techs to run into.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with a normal file system, as Chopper3 has pointed out. Trying to do this will quickly lead to data corruption. What you should do is either use a cluster-aware file system, or use a replication technology to synchronize two separate volumes, each presented to a single server.